# How to split a string but include some symbols (#'s and +'s)

Tags: javascript

Im looking to create pages from tags I've drawn from the stackoverflow API but I'm having difficulty with the c# and c++ tag as its only extracting the letter c. Is there any way I could include the two characters in my split method?

```
var tag = location.search.split('tag=')[1]
```

and the redirect function

```
    function reDirect()
  {
  d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
  window.location.assign("details.html?tag="+d.name);  
  }
```

Comment: for a simple `tag=c#`, I don't see why this wouldn't work. What is the full value of `location.search`?

Comment: Give some examples of `location.search`, some expected and actual output for those examples.

Comment: Im calling the nodes in a D3 force directed graph the code for this reDirect is now in the question

Comment: `"?tag=c#".split('tag=')` outputs `["?", "c#"]` and `"?tag=c++".split('tag=')` outputs `["?", "c++"]` which looks fine, so I don't know what's wrong. On the other hand when changing the location via `window.location.assign(...)`, d.name should be escaped `"details.html?tag=" + window.escape(d.name)` — you are simply not giving enough information about what/where things are not working. Your original `location.search.split('tag=')[1]` should work fine.

Comment: When I run window.location.assign("details.html?tag=c#");  
location.search.split('tag=')[1]; in my console I only get an output of c too.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your code is correct. The problem you are facing is that you are using the character `#` in your url. This characters is interpreted by the browser as a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

In order to be able to use the character `#` in your url, you should encode the value that you store in the "tag" query variable.

Storing the value in the url:

```
window.location.assign("details.html?tag=" + encodeURIComponent(d.name));
```

Retrieving the value from the url:

```
var tag = decodeURIComponent(location.search.split('tag=')[1]);
```